# Why its better to use find method in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm new to JavaScript. I'm refactoring a big code base (almost 10k in a single file). I have lines like this:

```
$('#idName tbody').empty();
```

WebStorm is suggesting me to change that fine to:

```
$('#serviceSearchResultTab').find("tbody")
```

why does it suggests `find` rather than the former way?

Comment: Because selectors are selected from right to left - all the `tbody`'s are first selected and then they're filtered by being a descendant of `#idName`. When you select the id first and then `find` it first finds an ID which is much faster and then looks for a tbody descendant. Not that it should matter for any practical case whatsoever. If you're not using an old browser both run through querySelectorAll rather than sizzle anyway.

Comment: You might find [**this**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dgI52y27O_I) interesting.